# Scripting with variables in RouterOS

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

I seem to be at a complete loss as to how Global variables work in RouterOS. My goal is to create a script which will make calls to other infrastructure components when DHCP leases are changed.

For each of the numerous DHCP servers, I intend to make a call to a system script which contains the actual logic.

DHCP Server Configuration:

```
:global leaseActIP
:log info ("Server Script Got: $leaseActIP")

/system script run LeaseChange
```

And in the System script *LeaseChange*

```
:global leaseActIP
:log info ("System Script Got: $leaseActIP")
```

However log output is:

> Server Script Got: 10.3.111.145
> System Script Got:

Question: How can I pass the variables available in the DHCP server script over to the System script?